# What encoding does my Konsole support?

Tags: kde, terminal, character-encoding

How can I check what encoding (ASCII, UTF-8, UTF-16 etc) my Terminal uses?

It shouldn't matter, but I am using Konsole on `KDE3.5`.

Comment: What exact version of Konsole are you using?

Comment: "uses" or "supports"? it should support any of those encodings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a [Unicode and UTF-8 FAQ for UNIX/Linux](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html): You can get a list of all locales installed on your system (usually in /usr/lib/locale/) with the command `locale -a`. Set the environment variable `LANG` to the name of your preferred locale.

Konsole supports whatever your system supports - the important thing is that you export `LANG` in your shell so that the programs you run display their characters using the correct locale.

Answer (score 2):

Konsole supports the encodings which **Qt** knows how to convert to/from Unicode.  It uses the **`QTextCodec`** class (see [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextcodec.html) which lists the supported encodings) which includes many but not necessarily all possible encodings which you may have installed on your system.

When you run Konsole, you can select (in the *Advanced* tab) an encoding from those which are tabulated in its runtime tables.

[image: Illustration of Konsole's encoding selection]

If you need an encoding which Konsole does not support, some people suggest that luit can be useful, e.g., in [IBMgraphics](http://nethack.wikia.com/wiki/IBMgraphics).